# Technique to detect request modification on server side using JWT

Tags: security, request, jwt, csrf

I want to know a technique with which server can identify if data coming in the request is not modified by an attacker. We are having REST APIs on server side which will be invoked from a mobile app client or a browser. I was thinking of using JWT (JSON Web Tokens). But not sure how it will achieve this. People have used JWT for session management purpose mostly. I do not need the session management. I just want to detect the request data modification. need some help here...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what type of attacker you wangt to protect against, but the TL;DR is you don't have to do anything as any such protection is either unnecessary (with some special case exceptions as detailed below) or useless.

#### Protecting against a valid user modifying his own requests

There is no point in this. Any secret you would use for such protection (for signing requests, essentially) would have to be sent to the client so that it can use it to sign whatever it wants to. But if it is sent to the client, the user already has it and can use it to sign any modified request. You have to architect the application in a way that security is enforced on the server side and valid users can't forge requests that they are not supposed to make.

#### Protecting against a man-in-the-middle attacker

Let's suppose you want to protect requests against somebody between the user and the server. If you access the server over a secure channel (https), it already does this for you, you don't have to implement anything in addition to that.

However, I can think of special cases. First, you may be worried about intermediate proxies that terminate SSL, like for example a company proxy that serves https websites with its own certificate, set as a trusted root on company clients. This is fairly common practice, but usually you as the application developer don't want to deal with this. The other thing is when you don't want to use SSL, but I'd say it's rather a special case when you are worried about request integrity, but not about confidentiality.

Anyway, if you are in a situation where you do in fact need to maintain integrity in another way besides (or instead of) https, you could give your client a secret and sign requests with that secret, like for example using HMAC or another message authentication protocol. You would take relevant fields from request headers and also the whole request body, create an HMAC of them with the secret and attach that to the request. The server, having the same secret for the client could create the same hash and verify if the client had the secret and also that the request sent is the same as signed by the user. Note that to prevent replay attacks, you would also have to include a timestamp and/or a nonce header in the signature.

The question then is how you get this secret to the client securely, and depending on your circumstances, this can be a tricky one to solve.

#### Edit

I just realized you had csrf as a tag to the question. Be aware that csrf has nothing to do with modified requests, and you do have to implement protection against csrf in general.

Answer (score 0):

> The JSON Web Signature is a cryptographic mechanism designed to secure data with a digital signature unique to the contents of the token in such a way that we are able to determine whether the data of the token has been tampered with or not.

source: [php-authorization-jwt-json-web-tokens](https://www.sitepoint.com/php-authorization-jwt-json-web-tokens/)

You can use JWT to verify client requests but the client need to request a token (at least once) before any verifiable request.

**Tokens are created on server side only** using a *secret key* (never sent to the client) used to encode/sign the token, **the client can decode and access the token but doesn't modify it, just send it back as it is**.